# Relation between server_name in nginx sites-available, /etc/hosts file and A-records

Tags: nginx, subdomain, hosts-file

I have the following two server-blocks in my config-file in sites-available:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name www.mydomain.be;

       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.html index.htm;


       location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       server_name sub.mydomain.be;

       root /usr/share/nginx/sub;
       index index.html index.htm;


       location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
}
```

I also created an A-record for both www.domain.be and sub.domain.be with the IP of my server as value.

Yet, when I try to reload my nginx configuration with
    service nginx reload
it fails.

When I remove the second server-block, it reloads as expected.

I know this topic is popular, and that there are loads of such [nginx][subdomain] questions here, but none of them seems to discuss explicitly how the following three things hang together:

1. virtual hosts or server blocks in nginx (est. server_name matching)
2. the effect of A-records on how nginx processes requests
3. the need to add hosts to /etc/hosts

Right now I have the impression that a lack of knowledge of this bigger picture, rather than specific knowledge of nginx configuration prevents me from making this work.

Update:

Tracked down the problem

Initially I got a fail without any explanation.

Using

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
```

I got this message

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase       server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
```

after uncommenting

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

the problem was resolved.

Comment: There seems to be a `server_name` missing in front of each of the names?

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected this, but I still get the same [fail] when I reload nginx.

Comment: Yes, but _why_ does it fail to reload?

Comment: I just got a [fail] without any more info, but now I've sorted out the problem. (question updated)

Comment: If you have resolved it, you can add your own answer to your own question and accept it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked down the problem (which isn't related to A-records or to the /etc/hosts file)

Initially I got a fail without any explanation.

Using

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
```

I got this message

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase       server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
```

after uncommenting

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

in nginx.conf the problem was resolved.